# Activated Custom Action for SharePoint Designer dosn't display sentence

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, custom-actions

My solution requires me to create a custom action for SharePoint Designer for a list. I have treed creating the custom action the old fashioned way (200 method) by creating the action and deploying it as a Farm Solution. Eventually (after many attempts and errors), I was able to get the custom action to appear  for SharePoint Designer. However once I selected the action, SharePoint Designer would not show the sentence.
Then I read about sandboxed solutions being able to deploy actions. Great! It even looks less complicated! However, even after following the [directions from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615449.aspx), I am unable to get the SPD 2010 to show the sentence add the action to the workflow editor. I copy and pasted the code present on that page.

I'm losing my mind here......

Comment: Found another gotcha, The feature you activate must be targeted at the site collection rather than on a web :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a tumbleweed award with this one....

After much gnashing of teeth, it comes down to making sure that the xml in the Action file ( or elements file if you throwing it on via a sandboxed solution) needs to be perfect. It is the weakest link in the whole process.

I eventully went with a sandboxed solution. It provided me with enough functionlity to get the job done. Below is an example of the correct way to declare an Action for a sandbox solution.

In this case the Action elements attributes ("Name","SandboxedFunction", etc) need to be accurate)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <WorkflowActions>
    <Action Name="Create a List"
        SandboxedFunction="true"
        Assembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
        ClassName="PMOCustomActions.ListCreation"
        FunctionName="CreateList"
        AppliesTo="all"
        UsesCurrentItem="true"
        Category="Resource Allocation">
      <RuleDesigner Sentence="Create a %1 list named %2, and described as %3">
        <FieldBind Id="1" Field="listType" DesignerType="Text" Text="list type"/>
        <FieldBind Id="2" Field="listTitle" DesignerType="Text" Text="list name"/>
        <FieldBind Id="3" Field="listDescription" DesignerType="Text" Text="description"/>
      </RuleDesigner>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" Direction="In" DesignerType="Hide" />
        <Parameter Name="listType" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" DesignerType="TextBox"/>
        <Parameter Name="listTitle" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" DesignerType="TextBox" />
        <Parameter Name="listDescription" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" DesignerType="TextBox" />
      </Parameters>
      </Action>
    </WorkflowActions>
</Elements>
```

Things to watch out for:

- Action elements attributes
  ("Name","SandboxedFunction", etc)
  need to be accurate
- Be sure to match    your id's with
  place holders (%1) in    the
  sentence.
- Use the correct Types    for both the
  RuleDesigner and the    Parameters.
- the __Context Parameter must always
  be there. It is the property bag for
  context information from the
  workflow.

If I remember the other gotchas, I'll come back and put them here.

Good luck.